# How to upload inputstream format via okhttp3 builder ? Android Q

Tags: okhttp, builder, android-10.0

I have used OkHttp3 for file upload, in Android Q i can't upload direct file URL, so I'm getting file URI from device. After that i need to upload video URI to OkHttp3. Is there any a way to upload inputstream in  buildMultipartEntity ???

```
private RequestBody buildMultipartEntity() {
        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (file[i].exists()) {
                    builder.addFormDataPart("files[]", file[i].getAbsolutePath(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/mp4"), file[i]));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
```